# Implement a method as a pure function to get size of a custom data structure iteratively (no recursion) and with space complexity O(1), so no copying

Tags: java

in a course I am doing, here is an example of the IntList class. With one recursive method to get the size of the list, getSizeRecursive() and one iterative method getSizeIterative().

```
public class IntList {
    public int first;
    public IntList rest;

    public IntList(int first, IntList L){
        this.first = first;
        this.rest = L;
    }

    public int getSizeIterative(){
        int size = 1;
        while (this.rest != null){
            size += 1;
            this.rest = this.rest.rest;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public int getSizeRecursive(){
        if (this.rest == null)
            return 1;
        else return 1 + rest.getSizeRecur();
    }
}
```

Now the iterative method gives the desired result too, like the recursive method, but only if I run it once, as it's changing the pointer to **rest** variable when it calls getSizeIterative(). So, I don't get the same result when I call the method twice. e.g.

```
IntList l = new IntList(10, null);
l = new IntList(15, l);
l = new IntList(5, l);
System.out.println(l.getSize()); // Outputs 3 as expected.
System.out.println(l.getSize()); // Outputs 1! <-- Wrong.
```

Now, I want to implement this method as a pure function, so I create a copy of the list in the getSizeIterative() method, like this:

```
public int getSizeIterative(){
    IntList copy = new IntList(first, rest); <-- Added this line.
    int size = 1;
    if (copy.rest != null){
        while (copy.rest != null){
            size += 1;
            copy.rest = copy.rest.rest;
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

But now it takes up more space. Is there a way to not use extra space? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
public int getSize(){
    IntList copy = this;
    int size = 1;
    while (copy.rest != null){
        size += 1;
        copy = copy.rest;
    }
    return size;
}
```

UPD. A bit of explanation. When you create new pointer to an object, like

```
IntList copy = this;
```

It's still one object in memory, but 2 different pointers on it. You can do something like

```
copy = null;
```

and it will not break **this** pointer, because you changed only pointer, not an object. However, if you change a field in **copy**, it changes field in **this** also. So, if you do like

```
copy.rest = copy.rest.rest;
```

this line changes **this.rest** also, because you changed real in-memory object, not only a pointer.

Comment: Hi. Yes it works! Thanks. I guess I understood pointers all wrong. Gonna look into it again.

Comment: More improvement on what a silly mistake I was making:
I thought that I cannot do **IntListcopy = this;** because then *copy* points to the same variable as *this*, and **whatever I do TO *copy*, happens TO *this* (wrong statement)**, so what's the point if in the loop I write **copy = copy.rest** instead of **this = this.rest**, but I was wrong. The correct statement is **whatever I do THROUGH *copy*, happen THROUGH *this*(correct statement)** But I can do TO copy anything I want, and nothing will happen to *this*